# Next 13.4 Problem adding .txt to the end of the link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have pushed my Next 13.4 application to my own server, but in the redirection, it adds ".txt" to the end of the link, and the page does not load. They suggest downgrading the version as a solution. Is there any other way to fix this?

example link
`/dashboard/user-managment/list.txt`

```
My next.config.js file is as follows

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `./.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});
console.log("NODE_ENV", process.env.NODE_ENV);
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export",
  trailingSlash: true,
  env: {
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
    ENV_VALUE: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

They said try to downgrade but I don't want to do that because I'm afraid some libraries will explode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.